# Isabelle - Code generation - typedef

Tags: code-generation, isabelle

I am trying to generate code from a very simple Isabelle-program.

```
typedef point = "{p::(real*real). True}" by(auto)
definition xCoord :: "point ⇒ real" where "xCoord P ≡ fst(Rep_point P)"

export_code xCoord in Haskell module_name Example file code
```

but get the error:

```
No code equations for Rep_point
```

anyway I do not understand. What exactly is missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register the type in the lifting and transfer package. Then code-generation works. Moreover, it is useful to not directly use `Rep_point`, but to use `lift_definition` instead, e.g., as in the following code.

```
setup_lifting type_definition_point

lift_definition xCoord :: "point ⇒ real" is fst .

export_code xCoord in Haskell module_name Example
```

Comment: Another solution would be to define point as a datatype, e.g. `datatype point = Point "real × real"`.